# Inconsistent string handling

Tags: vimscript, options, string-manipulation, set, join

I've been assembling strings in vimscript using a `.` as the join command.

But when I try and use the same command to join a string when setting an option, such as:

```
:setlocal foldtext=v:folddashes . "wtf?"
```

... I get `E518: Unknown option`.

Am I doing it wrong, or is the maker a sadist who likes to see people squirm?

Comment: `:help :set` doesn't accept expressions. Use `:help :execute` or `:help :let` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
:let &l:foldtext=v:folddashes . 'wtf?'
```